# Detect click event inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, tinymce

I'm writing a plugin for TinyMCE and have a problem with detecting click events inside an iframe.

From my search I've come up with this:

Loading iframe:

```
<iframe src='resource/file.php?mode=tinymce' id='filecontainer'></iframe>
```

HTML inside iframe:

```
<input type=button id=choose_pics value='Choose'>
```

jQuery:

```
//Detect click
$("#filecontainer").contents().find("#choose_pic").click(function(){
    //do something      
});
```

Other posts I've seen usually have a problem with different domains (this hasn't). But, still, the event isn't detected.

Can something like this be done?

Comment: So what exactly is the question, and what is'nt working with the above code ?

Comment: The event doesn't get triggered.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I solved it by doing like this:

```
$('#filecontainer').load(function(){

        var iframe = $('#filecontainer').contents();

        iframe.find("#choose_pics").click(function(){
               alert("test");
        });
});
```

Comment: `.load()` plays a key role here really

Comment: I get SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin... Looks like this is a security issues and gets blocked by Chrome.

Comment: jQuery 3:  `$('#filecontainer').on('load', function(){`

Comment: If anyone is interested in a "fully reproducible" version of the accepted answer see my post at the end,... - to save a few minutes for others ;) Can also be integrated in this answer with an edit, i just thought it might help others.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure, but you may be able to just use

```
$("#filecontainer #choose_pic").click(function() {
    // do something here
});
```

Either that or you could just add a `<script>` tag into the iframe (if you have access to the code inside), and then use `window.parent.DoSomething()` in the frame, with the code

```
function DoSomething() {
    // do something here
}
```

in the parent.
If none of those work, try `window.postMessage`. [Here is some info on that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage).

Comment: I have but i want the parent to capture some data from the iframe on click

Comment: Thanks, I used the `window.parent` solution which worked just great in my case!

Comment: Second one worked for my case as well. Up-voted as all other solutions didn't help at all.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#iframe-id").load( function() {
    $("#iframe-id").contents().on("click", ".child-node", function() {
        //do something
    });
});
```

Comment: Easy and clean solution

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old but the ID's don't match in your code one is **choose_pic** and one is **choose_pics**:

```
<input type=button id=choose_pics value='Choose'>

$("#filecontainer").contents().find("#choose_pic").click(function(){
    //do something      
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The tinymce API takes care of many events in the editors iframe. I strongly suggest to use them. Here is an example for the click handler

```
// Adds an observer to the onclick event using tinyMCE.init
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onClick.add(function(ed, e) {
           console.debug('Iframe clicked:' + e.target);
      });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just posting in case it helps someone. For me, the following code worked perfect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#payment_status_div").hide();
     var iframe = $('#FileFrame').contents();
     iframe.find("#take_payment").click(function(){
         $("#payment_status_div").show("slow");
     });
});
```

Where 'FileFrame' is the iframe id and 'take_payment' is the button inside iframe. Since my form inside the iframe is posted to a different domain, when used load, I got an error message saying:

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.example.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://secure-test.worldpay.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there were **two jQuery's**, for the inner and outer HTML. I had four steps before I could attach inner events:

1. wait for outer jQuery to be ready
2. wait for iframe to load
3. grab inner jQuery
4. wait for inner jQuery to be ready

---

```
$(function() {   // 1. wait for the outer jQuery to be ready, aka $(document).ready
    $('iframe#filecontainer').on('load', function() {   // 2. wait for the iframe to load
        var $inner$ = $(this)[0].contentWindow.$;   // 3. get hold of the inner jQuery
        $inner$(function() {   // 4. wait for the inner jQuery to be ready
            $inner$.on('click', function () {   // Now I can intercept inner events.
                // do something
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The trick is to use the inner jQuery to attach events. Notice how I'm getting the inner jQuery:

```
        var $inner$ = $(this)[0].contentWindow.$;
```

I had to bust out of jQuery into the object model for it. The `$('iframe').contents()` approach in the other answers didn't work in my case because that stays with the outer jQuery.  (And by the way returns `contentDocument`.)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested in a "quick reproducible" version of the **accepted answer**, see below. Credits to a friend who is not on SO. This answer can also be integrated in the accepted answer with an edit,...
(It has to run on a (local) server).

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SO</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
html,
body,
#filecontainer {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://localhost/tmp/fileWithLink.html" id="filecontainer"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#filecontainer').load(function(){

  var iframe = $('#filecontainer').contents();

  iframe.find("a").click(function(){
    var test = $(this);
    alert(test.html());
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

fileWithLink.html

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">SOreadytohelp</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to fire a custom event from the parent document, and receive it in the child iframe, so I had to do the following:

```
var event = new CustomEvent('marker-metrics', {
    detail: // extra payload data here
});
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
iframe[0].contentDocument.dispatchEvent(event)
```

and in the iframe document:

```
document.addEventListener('marker-metrics', (e) => {
  console.log('@@@@@', e.detail);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 $('#yourIframeid').on("load", function () {
            $(this).contents().on("contextmenu, keydown, mousedown, mouseup, click", function (e) {
               //do your thing
            });
           
        });
```

use  `$('#yourIframeid').on("load")` if  `$('#yourIframeid').onload(` does not work.

Comment: This won't work with CORS iframes.