# Detecting events in embedded youtube iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

**I want:**

Detect events in the youtube iframe. Examples are click and touchstart.

**My problem:**

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLpKom)

I get

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property
>   from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://s.codepen.io" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "https://www.youtube.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol
>   of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https".
>   Protocols must match.

I guess the problem comes from being logged into youtube.

**My code:**

HTML

```
<iframe id="someid" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tbaJS14t6Gw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

JS

```
$("#someid").load(function(){
  var iframe = $("iframe").contents();
console.error(iframe.find("body").length + "error happens above");

  $("iframe body").on("click", function(){
  alert("click");
});
  });
```

Further reading:

[Detect click event inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439303/detect-click-event-inside-iframe)

Comment: I think you are going to have trouble trying to communicate X-domain through the iFrame. Your linked question doesn't have this problem.