# Detect click in iframe and run script in parent (NOT same domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I would like to run the script **in parent** when .gridlove-sidebar-action is in iframe. **Iframe is NOT in the same domain**, but AccessControlAllowOrigin is "activated" in htaccess, css and script is working except this. The script is working if iframe is in same domain. I own the two domains.

Iframe :

```
<iframe id="followblog" src="http://example.com/iframe.html"></iframe>
```

In the Iframe :

```
<span class="gridlove-sidebar-action">
    <a class="#" href="#">
    My button
    </a>        
</span>
```

Script to run in parent :

```
$('#followblog').load(function(){

    var iframe = $('#followblog').contents();

    iframe.find(".gridlove-sidebar-action").click(function(){
        $('body').addClass('gridlove-sidebar-action-open gridlove-lock');
        $('.gridlove-sidebar-action-wrapper').css('top', gridlove_admin_top_bar_height);
    });
});
```

htaccess :

```
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(example.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
```

Comment: you need to use `jQuery` iframe `contents()` concept:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13782102/4248328

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726816/how-to-access-iframe-parent-page-using-jquery

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Defined in Parent window 
function defInParent(code){

}

// Call from Child iFrame 
window.opener.authSuccessWithCode(code);
```