# Capture click within iframe in a shiny app

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, iframe, shiny

I want to capture a click on a link within an iframe in a shiny app. And i want to know which link was clicked.

Outside shiny this works fine. I added a fully reproducible example for a related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46093537/3502164
(It has to run on a (local) server, e.g. `xaamp`).

My attempt:

1) The app to be saved in `Path/To/App`.

2) In the `www` folder store the html file that should be displayed within iframe.

`fileWithLink.html`

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">SOreadytohelp</a>
</body>
</html>
```

3) App has to be started with `runApp("Path/To/App", launch.browser = TRUE)`
(So that a local server is started).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  htmlOutput("filecontainer")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  session$onFlushed(once = T, function(){
      runjs("
          console.log('I arrive here')
          $('#filecontainer').load(function(){
            console.log('But not here')  
            var iframe = $('#filecontainer').contents();
            iframe.find('#a').click(function(){
              alert('I want to arrive here');
            });
          });
      ")
  })  

  output$filecontainer <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(src = "fileWithLink.html", height = 600, width = 1200)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iframe is enclosed in a div with relevant id (`$('#filecontainer iframe')`). There is a typo calling the anchor tags. I changed destination to avoid cross scripting issues:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  htmlOutput("filecontainer")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  session$onFlushed(once = T, function(){
    runjs("
          console.log('I arrive here')
          $('#filecontainer iframe').load(function(){
            console.log('But not here')  
            var iframe = $('#filecontainer iframe').contents();
            iframe.find('a').click(function(){
              console.log('am i here')  
              alert('I want to arrive here');
            });
          });
          ")
  })  

  output$filecontainer <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(src = "fileWithLink.html", height = 600, width = 1200)
  })
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

fileWithLink.html

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="anotherpage.html">SOreadytohelp</a>
</body>
</html>
```

anotherpage.html

```
<html>
<body>
Another page
</body>
</html>
```