# Redirect in Shiny app

Tags: r, redirect, shiny, httr

I'm trying to make my Shiny app to redirect the user to another page. I'm using `httr` to send `GET` requests and see if the user is logged in. If he's not, I want to redirect him to another link.

Can I do that using R / Shiny only, or do I need some extra libraries?

sample:

```
library(httr)
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
rv <- reactiveValues()
rv$mytoken = session$request$token

observeEvent(input$button1, {
  rv$a <- GET("my.url:3405/authtoken", 
              add_headers(
                .headers = c("token" = rv$mytoken)
              ))
  if (rv$a$status_code == 200) {
  } else {
    # redirect magic
  }
})
}

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  actionButton(button1, "btn")
))
```

Comment: Can you provide sample code with username and password?

Comment: It's working in a different way: i have auth token in the `session$request` environment, and i check with `GET` if it's the same on the server. So I redirect user based on status code I'm getting in response. I will provide some code if needed

Comment: You can still provide sample app without it, so when `false` then redirect

Comment: Is an example sufficient?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here this will navigate you to google if not `true`

```
library(shiny)

jscode <- "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('mymessage', function(message) {window.location = 'http://www.google.com';});"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(jscode)),     
  checkboxInput("Redirect","Redirect",value = T)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$Redirect,{
    if(!input$Redirect){
      session$sendCustomMessage("mymessage", "mymessage")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: As usual, you make it work :)The thing I was looking for, thank you! It seems though that you 'force' it to redirect the user. Doesn't shiny support this behaviour by default?

Comment: Its easy to do within the `ui` where you can bind buttons and links but you need to send it back the redirect from server and the`shiny` team added the `sendCustomMessage` which is very useful. So just go through it, you will pick it up quite fast

Comment: have a look at `paste`

Comment: Yeah yeah my bad, i'll handle it now. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, I don't know if I should create new question - if my app is inside an `iframe` - it seems that it redirects only inside it, and not the whole webpage. Unfortunately, I can't produce any examples here. Do you think by chance there is a way to redirect the whole page to another url, using only shiny?

Comment: There is an example how to capture click event within an `iframe` by John Harrison, have a look at that and study it, then you will be able to apply to your case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094396/capture-click-within-iframe-in-a-shiny-app/46164975#46164975

Comment: I just used `window.top.location.href` instead of `window.location` and it worked fine. Peace!

Comment: What if I need to include some reactive value in the url?

Comment: Is there no way to do this without JavaScript? Why can't the server side return a 302 response? Also what happens if JavaScript is disabled on client browser in this example?

Answer (score 6):

Just to update. There is also an easier way...

```
shinyjs::runjs(paste0('window.location.href = "...";'))
```

Don't forget `useShinyjs()` in UI.

Comment: Note your address must begin with `https://`