# Shiny open URL in the same window - trigger by observeEvent

Tags: r, shiny

I want to open a confirmation dialog and after clicking the confirm-button I want to open a URL within the same window. It will be a deployed app and `browseURL()` is not an option.

So far I have this:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  actionButton("open", "Click Me")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$open, {
    confirmSweetAlert(
      session = session,
      inputId = "confirm",
      title = "Please confirm."
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$confirm, {
    if (input$confirm) {
      browseURL('http://www.google.com')
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Are there any alternatives to `browseURL`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect in Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157880/redirect-in-shiny-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47158654/9993361).

This solves my problem and i can redirect to where I want.