# How to detect new tab URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, jquery-events

I'm having an `iframe` containing few anchors with `target="_blank"` attribute.

Whenever user clicks that anchor which will cause opening a new tab I would like to control that behaviour and handle it in my function.

(anchor URL's are always pointing to my website, not external ones)

I have tried using the `onunload` event, however it appears that its working only when action happens within that certain tab and not a new one.

Comment: Please refer this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439303/detect-click-event-inside-iframe

Comment: @hybrid I have seen that one before. I'm pretty sure there is a way not to relate this to the `iframe` and simply detect if an user has opened an `_blank` anchor somehow, hence the question. If this is not possible, I would love to get the answer on that with details.