# I am opening and external website in IFRAME. How to capture exact link clicked in the external website which is in Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, events, iframe, dom-events

I have a page which contains a Iframe. And i have opened an external website in that iframe.I want to capture the exact link which is clicked inside the iframe using pure Javascript. Below is my iframe code.

```
<iframe id = "frame" src="" name="iframe_a" width = 100% height = 100% style="border:none;""> </iframe>

 

var monitor = setInterval(function()
{
var elem = document.activeElement;
if(elem && elem.tagName == 'IFRAME')
 {
    elem.blur();
    console.log(iframe_a.href);
  //console.log("clicked");
}
  }, 100);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect click event inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439303/detect-click-event-inside-iframe)

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a").forEach(function(el){
     el.addEventListener("click", function(el){
         //here is your link value
         var link = el.currentTarget.getAttribute('href');
         //return false;
     });
});
```

Comment: Your answer may be correct, but an explanation would help other readers. For more info read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I am opening and external website in Iframe and i need the link which is getting clicked in Iframe

Comment: capturing windows.location.href worked for me at last